# Is there a limit in Gensim's Doc2Vec most_similar documents result set?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I have been experimenting with the doc2vec module for sometime now. I can train my model and have the trained model output similar documents for a given document as follows :

```
import re
modelloaded=Doc2Vec.load("model_all_doc_dm_1")

st = 'long description of a document as string'
doc = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', st).lower().split() 

new_doc_vec = modelloaded.infer_vector(doc)

modelloaded.docvecs.most_similar([new_doc_vec])
```

This works well, and gives me 10 results. Is there a way to get more than 10 results or is that the limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it:

```
modelloaded.docvecs.most_similar([new_doc_vec], topn=N)
```

the `topn=N` handle can be used to get more than 10 results.

Comment: [docs](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Doc2Vec.most_similar.html)